# Efficiently re-using views

Tags: wpf, mvvm

We have a list of items in a `TreeView` where users can select the item they want. Every item can be associated with another item. I have a button on my `ItemEditor` view that opens a new window with the associated item in read-only mode. The read-only copy of the item has no save functionality nor does it give any of the edits made by previous users. It does however share 90% of the fields, out of ~50.

Do I take the hit in almost duplicating the entire view and create a pure `ReadOnlyItemViewModel`? Or is it typically more acceptable to set flags in my view model to display which editable items are hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map multiple views onto the same View Model. It's actually encouraged. You don't have to make a ReadOnlyItemViewModel...just make a View on top of the ItemViewModel. If you are trying to auto-generate the view, make whether it generates read-only or fully editable view a strategy of the generator. If you need more fine grain control consider adding attributes that express how a field should be displayed in Read-Only vs. Editable mode. Only after you've explored all those avenues should you consider splitting the VM into two.

Comment: Nice answer. Could you please expand on where you talk about generating a read-only or fully editable view strategy? Thank you.

Comment: Because of the declarative nature of WPF, you are able to very easily create a view dynamically. (In fact the Silverlight DataForm control does just that). You can create a control that works similar to the Dataform and extend it with the capability to generate a read-only version based on a property.